# Complex Error Function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The [complex error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) w(z) is defined as `e^(-x^2) erfc(-ix)`. The problem with using w(z) as defined above is that the erfc tends to explode out for larger x (complemented by the exponential going to 0 so everything stays small), so that Mathematica reverts to arbitrary precision calculations that make life VERY slow. The function is used in implementing the voigt profile - a line shape commonly used in spectroscopy and other related areas. Right now I'm reverting to calculating the lineshape once and using an interpolation to speed things up, however this doesn't let me alter the parameters of the lineshape (or fit to them) easily.

scipy has a nice and fast implementation of w(z) as `scipy.special.wofz`, and I was wondering if there is an equivalent in Mathematica.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around in that the error function blows up and the exponential decays for x large (and real)?

Comment: I tried playing with `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow"->False]`, which, however, results in getting `0. +0. I` for large arguments. Then I tried defining the function as `Exp[Log[-z^2+Log@Erfc[-I*z]]]`, but this turns out to not be any faster than with automatic switching. So, it seems hard to speed this up, except as @Daniel Lichtblau suggests

Comment: @Heike you are right, a bit of a slip on my part.

Answer (score 5):

The complex error function can be written in terms of the Hermite "polynomial" `H_{-1}(x)`:

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[2 HermiteH[-1,I x] == Sqrt[Pi] Exp[-x^2] Erfc[I x]]
Out[1]= True
```

And the evaluation does not suffer as many underflows and overflows

```
In[68]:= 2 HermiteH[-1, I x] /. x -> 100000.
Out[68]= 6.12323*10^-22 - 0.00001 I

In[69]:= Sqrt[Pi] E^-x^2 Erfc[I x] /. x -> 100000.
During evaluation of In[69]:= General::unfl: Underflow occurred in computation. >>
During evaluation of In[69]:= General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>
Out[69]= Indeterminate
```

That said, some quick tests show that the evaluation speed of the Hermite function to be slower than that of the product of the exponential and error function...

Answer (score 4):

A series expansion at infinity shows that the real and imaginary parts are of very different scales. I'd suggest computing them separately and not adding them. Below I use the first few terms of the series expansion to get the imaginary part.

```
In[186]:= 
w[x_?NumericQ] := {N[Exp[-SetPrecision[x, 25]^2], 20], 
  N[(3 /(4 Sqrt[\[Pi]] x^5) + 1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] x^3) + 1/(
     Sqrt[\[Pi]] x))]}

In[187]:= w[11]

Out[187]= {2.8207700884601354011*10^-53, 0.05150453151309212}

In[188]:= w[1000]

Out[188]= {3.296831478088558579*10^-434295, 0.0005641898656429712}
```

Not sure how badly you want that very small real part. If you can drop it that will keep the numbers in a reasonable range. In some ranges (or if higher than machine precision is desired) you may want to use more terms from the expansion on that imaginary part.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: Because the real part is effectively zero far enough out (and the voigt profile is defined as the real part of w(z)) it would suffice for me to just set the whole thing to 0 far enough out (say before mathematica switches to arbitrary precision - but I'm not very well versed with the mechanism) since in the end I'm doing a numerical fit, and 10^-53 is well below the machine sigma for floating point.

Answer (score 4):

The real and imaginary parts of the complex error function on the real line can be explicitly and efficiently computed in Mathematica using [Dawson integral](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DawsonF.html):

```
In[9]:= Sqrt[Pi] Exp[-x^2] Erfc[I x] == 
  E^-x^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] - 2 I DawsonF[x] // FullSimplify

Out[9]= True
```

This is about 4 times faster than using `HermiteH[-1,z]`.

```
In[10]:= w1[x_] := E^-x^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] - 2 I DawsonF[x]
w2[x_] := 2 HermiteH[-1, I x]

In[15]:= AbsoluteTiming[w1 /@ Range[-5.0, 5.0, 0.001];]

Out[15]= {2.3272327, Null}

In[16]:= AbsoluteTiming[w2 /@ Range[-5.0, 5.0, 0.001];]

Out[16]= {10.2400239, Null}
```

Comment: I was running some old code (from 2007) the other day and the manual `erf` simplification/replacement rules were broken because of those `DawsonF` functions. They're new in version 7. Do you know where they arise and why they were added to Mma?

Comment: @Simon if "where they arise" refers to applications, I have met them in doing path integral monte carlo (or generally working with imaginary time actions). I would imagine the main attraction is that there exist approximations for these functions for which the series converge very rapidly indeed (then again I only know this from numerical recipes, and have never used these functions in anger myself)

Comment: @Simon Given that [Dawson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_M._Dawson) was active in plasma research, I expect the integral to arise in plasma physics, although I have not seen the use myself.

Answer (score 1):

A program in language C for the complex error function (aka the Faddeeva function) that can be run from Mathematica is also available in [RooFit](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0748v1.pdf). Read the article by [Karbach *et al.* arXiv:1407.0748](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0748v1.pdf) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the C library [libcerf](http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/libcerf).

Comment: This is not really a Mathematica answer unless you show how to call that library from Mathematica (in a simpler way than the scipy one the OP mentions).  [Also, it would have been in order to at least disclose your affiliation.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)

Comment: Calling C from Mathematica is standard, http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CLanguageInterface.html. And yes, it's me who published libcerf, sorry and thanks for informing me about the disclosure rule.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke Would you happen to have an example of how to use libcerf from Mathematica? Looking at the wolfram documentation it seems like I'd have to start messing with the source code, so if you already have a working implementation I'd much prefer to use that.

Comment: @Jordan, no so far I have no example. But if somebody points me to one, then I will be glad to add it to the libcerf distribution.