# Mathlink and delayed evaluation/variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

I have a scalar function written in Fortran that I'm using in Mathematica via a small mathlink module. I want this function to behave as close to a native Mathematica function as possible, including its handling of symbolic constants.

A lot of times I wish to write some expression in mathematica with symbolic constants/variables that will be replaced latter on with a list of replacement rules. However, Mathematica immediately tries to evaluate my mathlink function with the symbolic arguments in place and it obviously fails. For example, even the following simple expression will fail

```
extf[a]/.a->5
```

Is there a way to delay the evaluation of the function until all symbolic arguments have been replaced with numbers?

One not so elegant way I have used with some success (but not acceptable If I wish to include this function in a general purpose mathematica package to share with coworkers) is to evaluate everything with a "dummy" reference to the external function and then use a replacement rule to swap all dummy references for the real reference at the same time I evaluate all the other numerical constants. e.g.

```
dummyf[a]/.{a->5,dummyf->extf}
```

Comment: what kind of argument pattern did you use? It is my understanding that if the argument pattern doesn't match the function returns unevaluated. At that moment, the replacement should kick in and your function should be evaluated with a numeric argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would something using the Mathematica pattern matcher be useful? Note that you need to omit any definition for `holddummyf` when the input is non-numeric.

```
dummyf[a_?NumericQ] := extf[a]
holddummyf[a_?NumericQ] := extf[a]
dummyf[a_] := holddummyf[a]

[In]  dummyf[0.3]
[Out] extf[0.3]

[In]  dummyf[b]
[Out] holddummyf[b]

[In]  % /. b -> 5
[Out] extf[5]
```

I guess the other question to ask is whether having `extf` in Fortran is strictly necessary.

Comment: I don't think you need the `holddummyf` stuff at all.  Without it `dummyf` will just return unevaluated if the argument isn't a number.

Comment: Works perfectly, I haven't used pattern matching for parameters before and I didn't even know Mathematica had this functionality. extf is taken from a python library (its an optimized numerical routine for computing the complex error function), it could be written in Mathematica, but it will take more time, and I just want a drop-in optimized function to speed up my code in the short term.

Comment: @Brett, good point. I had originally thought he would want to have a general definition for `dummyf[a_]` rather than using the trick of leaving that undefined, so then it needs something else undefined. It's clearer what is going on then. But I can edit my answer.

Comment: @crasic - is there a reason Mathematica's own `Erfi` functions aren't sufficiently fast? http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ErrorAndExponentialIntegralFunctions.html

Comment: @Verbeia Yeah, I made a question about this on SE  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805164/complex-error-function-in-mathematica - note that the complex error function  w(z) is not the same as the erf or erfi. The scipy version is faster and more accurate than any of the proposed solutions to that question and since it was in fortran I decided to use it for the time being (it also gave me an excuse to learn mathlink)